# home page without htpasswd in codigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, apache2

I have a site in development, and I do have enabled htpasswd for hiding my development work.
I was wondering if I can have home page without htpasswd protection. I'm using codeigniter as my framework.
  Is there is way I can make the my www.domain.com protection less and asd.domain.com, www.domain.com/abc with password protected via htaccess and htpasswd ?

In my virtualhost in Apache I have setup

```
 ServerName domain.com
 ServerAlias *.domain.com
 DocumentRoot /home/m4k/public_html/domain/
```

Answer (score 0):

All sites CI?

If so, a KIS would be to add an include in top of controller that

- Check `['SERVER_NAME']`
- If protected site, check IP / cookie or whatever security you'd like
- If cookie-pwd, add side script that set cookie upon successful password.